# Showing/Hiding Rows in Sections of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray, ipad

I am trying to create a UITableView that is set up so that when I click on a section, it hides the rows from the previous section and shows the rows of the newly selected section. The tableView is set up with data from an array of arrays called menuItems. menuItems contains several other arrays including contactInfoArray, clientInfoArray, jacketArray, and shirtArray. In each of these arrays, the objectAtIndex:0 is the Section Title and effectively acts as the header.

So, for example when the app loads, it should first show all rows of the contactInfoArray, but then show the ObjectAtIndex:0 (the title) for each of the other arrays. When I then tap one of those section titles, for example: "Jacket", I need the table to hide the contactInfoArray objectsAtIndexes:1+, but not object 0, while at the same time (or with an acceptable delay) showing jacketArray objectsAtIndexes:1+.

I have achieved the desired result by calling reload data, but I want animation of the change and reloadData does not allow that. I can't find any tutorials or sample code that does this.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to my good friend Darren for helping me solve this issue!

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return (indexPath.section == currentSection) ? [[menuItems objectAtIndex: indexPath.section ] count] : 1;
}
```

All that I needed to do was set an immediate variable (in my case "currentSection" which is an int) and set its value in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. Then I set up my table so that row 0 of the section acted as the section title.

Doing this made it so that when I clicked on the section header it would "collapse" the open section and "expand" the newly selected section.